# Present Drupal 8 Custom widget choice only in certain context

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I have a custom Drupal 8 widget for textfields, which I only want to present as choice in the "Manage Form Display", if the textfield is attached to a certain entity type, in fact only to a certain media entity type. The widget makes no sense in other contexts. I don't want to create a custom field type just for the purpose of filtering out field formatters.

Any ideas. Is there a hook I can access here?

thanks ...

Comment: Could you explain what your widget is doing? I understand your question but can't think of a scenario where it makes sense to make widgets dependent on a entity bundle.

Comment: Well the text field is populated by an image-id from an image service. The textfield is attached to a custom image-entity type, and on saving, the image entity type loads the image into the entity. The widget attached to the text field only makes sense in that context, since it provides a browser for the image service, and populates the textfield with the image id.

Comment: What I was envisioning, was that in place of the annotation definition of the fields to which the widget belongs, there could be a callback instead, in which I could filter not just by field type, but also by, entity and even media-entity-type (i.e. my custom type).   It's ok without this, but it could confuse people.

Comment: So if I understand correctly it's basically a select list with possible image ids/images? So the user can select some image out of that list and save? if yes, then why don't you just use the entity reference field type? It does exactly that (let's you select the target entity/bundle, search by name/id/custom field, etc.)

Comment: Not quit. As I mentioned above, it is an image browser hooked up to a remote image service. No, and entity reference field won't hack it. In any case, I am asking a question about whether it is possible to make the allowed field types of a custom widget context sensitive. Is there a callback which can determine that, or is it always hard coded  in the annotations of the widget class?

Comment: Ok, afaik there's no out-of-the-box solution for that. You could try and hack it yourself with the "hook_form_FORM_ID_alter" hook... https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/8.2.x